# errors:Type 'HomeController' already defines a member called 'Index' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET and currently building an ASP.NET simple app with some data static and displaying it in an index.cshtml with the controller to handle and showcase that in the view. I was wondering is it alright that I paste the data static inside the home controller but I got the following errors, can you help, please? thank you!

```
namespace MYWEB_MVC_.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController: Controller

    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error already defines a member called 'Index' with the same parameter types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012213/error-already-defines-a-member-called-index-with-the-same-parameter-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have 2 methods with same name and same param

```
public IActionResult Index()
```

Pasting static data in controller is just fine, it doesn't cause any compile error.

Comment: thanks @Alex but its not even the same, one is public IActionResult Index(), another one is public ActionResult Index()

Comment: You cannot have different return types. Method overloading is only for parameters.

Comment: oh ok got it! thanks!!Can i just simply remove this line of code? :public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: Yes, the first method doesnt do anything, you can remove it. And change 2nd method return type to IActionResult pls. Try to use the interface.

Comment: oh yes, sure! not it says '''not all code paths return a value'''

Comment: You need return View() at the end of your 2nd method.

Comment: yes! thank you  Alex, that works!!